# How to get the range of currently visible dates of table_calendar flutter?

Tags: flutter, table-calendar

Each time I go to a new page in my calendar, I would like to get the range of dates displayed in a Page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: eg . If my calendar is in week view format and it displays the dates from 29th May to 4th June, how to access the variable which stores this range of date from 29th May to 4th June

Answer (score 1):

In the table_calendar codebase, specifically in `calendar_core.dart` file,
There is a private method: [_getVisibleRange(CalendarFormat format, DateTime focusedDay)](https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/05db2a2024a78f5ade30eb7b87b0037a829f8a8a/lib/src/widgets/calendar_core.dart#LL218C24-L218C24). You can use it to get visibleRange

You can copy these private method into your widget.

```
DateTimeRange _getVisibleRange(CalendarFormat format, DateTime focusedDay) {
    switch (format) {
      case CalendarFormat.month:
        return _daysInMonth(focusedDay);
      case CalendarFormat.twoWeeks:
        return _daysInTwoWeeks(focusedDay);
      case CalendarFormat.week:
        return _daysInWeek(focusedDay);
      default:
        return _daysInMonth(focusedDay);
  }
}

DateTimeRange _daysInWeek(DateTime focusedDay) {
  final daysBefore = _getDaysBefore(focusedDay);
  final firstToDisplay = focusedDay.subtract(Duration(days: daysBefore));
  final lastToDisplay = firstToDisplay.add(center code hereonst Duration(days: 7));
  return DateTimeRange(start: firstToDisplay, end: lastToDisplay);
}

DateTimeRange _daysInTwoWeeks(DateTime focusedDay) {
  final daysBefore = _getDaysBefore(focusedDay);
  final firstToDisplay = focusedDay.subtract(Duration(days: daysBefore));
  final lastToDisplay = firstToDisplay.add(const Duration(days: 14));
  return DateTimeRange(start: firstToDisplay, end: lastToDisplay);
}

DateTimeRange _daysInMonth(DateTime focusedDay) {
  final first = _firstDayOfMonth(focusedDay);
  final daysBefore = _getDaysBefore(first);
  final firstToDisplay = first.subtract(Duration(days: daysBefore));

  if (sixWeekMonthsEnforced) {
    final end = firstToDisplay.add(const Duration(days: 42));
    return DateTimeRange(start: firstToDisplay, end: end);
  }

  final last = _lastDayOfMonth(focusedDay);
  final daysAfter = _getDaysAfter(last);
  final lastToDisplay = last.add(Duration(days: daysAfter));

  return DateTimeRange(start: firstToDisplay, end: lastToDisplay);
}
```

Then you can call it to get visibleRange

```
final visibleRange = _getVisibleRange(_calendarFormat!, _focusedDay);
DateTime start = visibleRange.start;
DateTime end = visibleRange.end
```